# What is the Typescript Typing for scrollXAnimated in React Native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, types, typescript-typings

What is the Typescript Typing for `scrollXAnimated` in React Native? I've looked through the docs and haven't seen anything for this.

**TypeScript Type:**

```
// TypeScript Type: Props
interface Props {
  scrollXAnimated: any, // WHAT CAN I ADD INSTEAD OF ANY?
  data: any,
};
```

**The Code:**

```
  const translateY = props.scrollXAnimated.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-1, 0, 1],
    outputRange: [HEADER_HEIGHT, 0, -HEADER_HEIGHT],
  });
```

Comment: its Animated.Value if Animated from react native if its from reanimated it will be Animated.Value<number>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface

```
interface Props {
  scrollXAnimated: Animated.Value // if from . react native else Animated.Value<number> if from reanimated
  data: any,
};
```